# Specifying the json file for some visualization via a dropdown box

Tags: d3.js

I've recently started trying out d3.js for visualization. I don't have much of a background in JS or web scripting, so sorry if this is an easy thing that I'm asking.

The exact example doesn't matter too much. I am making a graph, something like [this](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html)

I want there to be a drop down menu on the page that lists different data sources. The user could then select the data source and the graph would update.

I created a drop down menu using the example [here](http://www.idocs.com/tags/linking/linking_famsupp_137.html). However, I am unsure how to get the value as I need the line

```
d3.json("miserables.json", function(json) {
```

to update with the new name.

Answer (score 7):

Your html file should look something like this...

```
<select id="json_sources" name="json_sources">
    <option value ="source1.json" selected>Source 1</option>
    <option value ="source2.json">Source 2</option>
    <option value ="source3.json">Source 3</option>
</select>​
```

Then you add an event listener for the `change` event on the select element (`.on` in d3.js):

```
var dropdown = d3.select("#json_sources")
var change = function() {
  var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;
  d3.json(source, function(json) {
     //continue doing stuff here.
  })
}

dropdown.on("change", change)
change(); //trigger json on load
```

Comment: Thanks, I see why this should work, but I am still having a problem. When I change the drop down, the graph reloads but not with new data. The only javascript code I have outside of what you have (with stuff filled in the function) is declaring vis=d3.select("body").append("svg:svg"). If I put this inside the function, a graph is created below the graph each time. I need to modify it so it replaces the graph instead.

Comment: You need to put your visualization in a div, say, `<div id="viz"></div>` and then try `vis=d3.select("#viz").empty().append("svg:svg")`

Comment: When I used empty() it did not work and when I left that out it was the same as before. However, I realized that when I refreshed the page, it would have the right output. So I put a button on the page that the user can click that reloads the page which now has the correct graph. So your original solution worked, but the page needs to be refreshed after the change. There is probably a way to do this automatically without a button, but a button works for me. Thanks for all your help!!